# Creating Computed column from two different tables

Tags: sql-server

please i need help on how to create computed column. for example I a hav tables A, B, C. which has columns as A(i, ii ), B(1,2) now I want to multiple A(ii) and B(1) and store the result in C(i)

thanks please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help on asking a good question. It will be much easier to help you if you can 1) Provide the database client you are using (MySQL, Oracle, etc.), 2) Provide samples of what your table data looks like, and 3) Provide a sample of what you are trying to make your output look like.

Answer (score 1):

Computed columns can reference only local columns.

**Option 1 (synchronous).**

Create INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE triggers on A and B tables, so any change in A or B table will trigger updating the values in Table C.

**Option 2 (asynchronous).**

Create a job that updates Table C for all updated rows (since last run) in table A and B

**Option 3 (don't store calculated value).**

Calculate the value on fly when you need it by joining relevant tables (A and B), or create a view that joins tables A, B and C and use that view instead of direct usage of table C.